# Cypress - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_currentRetry')

Tags: cypress, test-runner

I'm having an issue I can't manage to fix with some Cypress tests.

I have the test file "run_tests.cy.js", that contains the following:

```
describe('Run tests', () => {
    it('Run all tests', () =>{
        require('../path/to/test_1.cy.js');
        require('../path/to/test_2.cy.js');
        require('../path/to/test_3.cy.js');
        require('../path/to/test_4.cy.js');
        require('../path/to/test_5.cy.js');
        require('../path/to/test_6.cy.js');
        require('../path/to/test_7.cy.js');
    })
})
```

And I have a custom script in my `package.json` file:

```
"cy:run:test": "cypress run --browser chromium --config baseUrl=https://google.com/ --spec './cypress/e2e/path/to/run_tests.cy.js'",
```

When I run the test manually, aka `npx cypress open`, selecting E2E testing, selecting chromium and selecting the test. It works as intended (the test works)

The problem is when I try and run my custom script `npm run cy:run:test` I get the following error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_currentRetry')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_currentRetry')
    at E.<anonymous> (<embedded>:4644:13577)
    at E.parseArgs (<embedded>:4644:16785)
    at E.emit (<embedded>:4644:16602)
    at Object.onMocha (<embedded>:4691:427158)
    at p.<anonymous> (<embedded>:4691:68249)
    at p.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at p.emitUntyped (<embedded>:4402:84346)
    at <embedded>:4402:91863
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

Any idea what I can do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I am speculating that `test_1.cy.js` already contain `it()` blocks, which would mean that you effectively nest it-blocks with `it('Run all tests', () => { require('../path/to/test_1.cy.js')`

Another clue, `_currentRetry` is a property of `test` which is the internal object for an it-block. So maybe the Cypress runner is confused about what is the test.

```js
describe('Run all tests', () => {
  require('../path/to/test_1.cy.js');
  require('../path/to/test_2.cy.js');
  ...
})
```

This would be legitamate, since you *can* nest `describe()` blocks.

Comment: You are right about the ```test_1.cy.js``` having an it() block.

If I am to remove this, how should the ```test_1.cy.js``` be constructed? Just having the ```cy.get``` commands without it() and describe() ?

Comment: Well you can probably make `test_1.cy.js` have a function in place of `it()` block, and export that function and in `run-all-tests.js` use `const {test1Fn} = require('../path/to/test_1.cy.js'); test1Fn();`. But above pattern is easier, means no change in `test_1.cy.js`.

Comment: Plus with the above pattern, each imported file is separate test, so they can run independently.